# Rails: Is it safe to use params[:bar] in link_to helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xss

Is it safe to use the `link_to` helper like this in a view or would I have to sanitize `params[:bar]` in order to prevent XSS attacks?

```
link_to("name", my_path(foo: params[:bar]))
```

I use Rails 4.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameters are sanitized. No worries. This is a fragment from a Rails console with an example.

[image: Pry session with in a Rails console]

Comment: I've actually just reread the question and I realised I checked the wrong argument, that was stupid `.-.` Then it's likely that you should be concerned about safety of a route helper. I would bet it's safe too, but better safe than sorry. Don't rush yet.

Answer (score 1):

`params[:bar]` simply returns a value, which could be a `String`, `Fixnum`, `Array`, etc.  It is no different than passing any other `link_to` params.  No additional caution beyond Rails' conventions is needed since your example will only be sending a `GET` request.

As @tadman mentioned, `link_to` will handle properly escaping this, so you can put in arbitrary data without concern for XSS.

If you will be changing it to a `POST`, `PUT`, `PATCH`, or `DELETE` request, consider using [`button_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to) instead.

Comment: It's worth noting that `link_to` will handle properly escaping this, so you can put in arbitrary data here without concern for XSS.